# How can I wrap the long label text in the bubble chart in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using D3 version 3, I'm very new to D3, like today is my day 2 for d3.......I need to do this project put each category in bubble....I was given the following D3 codes from class, professor said just change the data set to make it work....but my data label is way too long to fit in each bubble....Due to I have 0 knowledge about D3, although I did found some codes about how to wrap the text, but I have no idea how to put it there. Please help~~

This is the D3 version 3 codes given by professor:

```
var diameter = 800, //max size of the bubbles
   color = d3.scale.category20(); //color category

var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
.sort(null)
.size([diameter, diameter])
.padding(1.5);

var svg = d3.select("section")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", diameter)
.attr("height", diameter)
.attr("class", "bubble");

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data){

//convert numerical values from strings to numbers
data = data.map(function(d){ d.value = +d["Amount"]; return d; });

//bubbles needs very specific format, convert data to this.
var nodes = bubble.nodes({children:data}).filter(function(d) { return !d.children; });

//setup the chart
var bubbles = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .selectAll(".bubble")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter();

//create the bubbles
bubbles.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d){ return d.r; })
    .attr("cx", function(d){ return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d){ return d.y; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.value); });

//format the text for each bubble
bubbles.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d){ return d.x; })
    .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y + 5; })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d){ return d["Item"]; })
    .style({
        "fill":"white", 
        "font-family":"Verdana, san-serif",
        "font-size": "12px"
    });
})
```

And this is my data.csv that I'm using:

```
Item,Amount
Daily Phone Pick-ups on Average: 183 Counts ,182
Daily Screen Time: 401 minutes,401.4
Daily Walking & Running Distance: 0.188 miles,188.36
Daily Steps: 44 Counts,448
Daily Flights Climbed: 39 Counts,393
```

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slightly simplified version of [this technique](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321):

```
bubbles.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return d.y + 5;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d["Item"];
    })
    .style({
      "fill": "white",
      "font-family": "Verdana, san-serif",
      "font-size": "12px"
    })
    .each(wrap);

function wrap(d) {
    var text = d3.select(this),
      width = d.r * 2,
      x = d.x,
      y = d.y,
      words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
      word,
      line = [],
      lineNumber = 0,
      lineHeight = 1.1,
      tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y);
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
}
```

Running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.17" data-semver="3.5.17" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section></section>
  <script>
    var diameter = 800, //max size of the bubbles
      color = d3.scale.category20(); //color category

    var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
      .sort(null)
      .size([diameter, diameter])
      .padding(1.5);

    var svg = d3.select("section")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", diameter)
      .attr("height", diameter)
      .attr("class", "bubble");

    //d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
      
      var data = [{"Item":"Daily Phone Pick-ups on Average: 183 Counts ","Amount":"182"},{"Item":"Daily Screen Time: 401 minutes","Amount":"401.4"},{"Item":"Daily Walking & Running Distance: 0.188 miles","Amount":"188.36"},{"Item":"Daily Steps: 44 Counts","Amount":"448"},{"Item":"Daily Flights Climbed: 39 Counts","Amount":"393"}];

      //convert numerical values from strings to numbers
      data = data.map(function(d) {
        d.value = +d["Amount"];
        return d;
      });

      //bubbles needs very specific format, convert data to this.
      var nodes = bubble.nodes({
        children: data
      }).filter(function(d) {
        return !d.children;
      });

      //setup the chart
      var bubbles = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
        .selectAll(".bubble")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter();

      //create the bubbles
      bubbles.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) {
          return d.r;
        })
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
          return d.x;
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          return d.y;
        })
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return color(d.value);
        });

      //format the text for each bubble
      bubbles.append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.x;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return d.y + 5;
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d["Item"];
        })
        .style({
          "fill": "white",
          "font-family": "Verdana, san-serif",
          "font-size": "12px"
        })
        .each(wrap);
    //})

    function wrap(d) {
        var text = d3.select(this),
          width = d.r * 2,
          x = d.x,
          y = d.y,
          words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
          word,
          line = [],
          lineNumber = 0,
          lineHeight = 1.1,
          tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y);
        while (word = words.pop()) {
          line.push(word);
          tspan.text(line.join(" "));
          if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
            line.pop();
            tspan.text(line.join(" "));
            line = [word];
            tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + "em").text(word);
          }
        }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```